# Getting the value from an input after it has been save into an inline on click variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When a user presses the Save Button inside a document on click event in jQuery, the value of is stored inside a hidden input. I'm struggling to get the value of this input to display inside an onclick event inside the link below the input to be able to detect the value and delete the item if the user requires. I need to achieve this without having to refresh the page.

```
$(document).on('click','.addItem', function(){

    $('<div class="col3">\
        <input type="hidden" class="itemId" name="itemId[]" value="">\
        <a class="rowDeleteButton" onclick="onclick="deleteItem($(this))">Delete Button</a>\
        <div class="saveButton rowSave">Save Button</div>\
    </div>')

});
```

I require after the Save Button has been pressed that the value stored inside the value="" of the hidden input is also stored inside the onclick event for the Delete Button link.

Comment: This is not clear, at all. That code doesn't appear to do much.

Comment: you have error in this line onclick="onclick="deleteItem($(this))"

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more clearly as it is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in

```
onclick="onclick="deleteItem($(this))
```

I think simply passing *this* to the function is enough. I also prefer [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You can try the following way:

```js
$(document).on('click','.addItem', function(){

    $(this).append(`<div class="col3">
        <input type="hidden" class="itemId" name="itemId[]" value="hiddenTestValue">
        <a class="rowDeleteButton" onclick="deleteItem(event,this)">Delete Button</a>
        <div class="saveButton rowSave">Save Button</div>
    </div>`)
  
});

function deleteItem(e, el){
  var hdInput = $(el).parent().find('.itemId');
  console.log('value before:',hdInput[0].value);
  hdInput[0].value = '';
  console.log('value after:',hdInput[0].value);
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addItem">Test</div>
```